# ContactForm. Return div instead of a new htmlPage on [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm having a contactForm in a view. When I hit submit the method below starts. In the try/catch section it now returns a new blank page with the content written in "return Content("Message was sent")". How can I instead return the original ContactForm-View with just a nice div under the form saying "Message was sent".

Here is the [HttpPost]-Method code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMail(string SenderName, string SenderAddress, string phone, string Message)
    {
        const string username = "myMail@gmail.com";
        const string password = "myPassword";
        var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        var msg = new MailMessage();

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = loginInfo
        };

        string message = SenderName + " have a message for you:<br /><br /><br />" + Message
                         + "<br /><br />Avs. Phone: " + phone
                         + "<br /><br />Avs. Mail: " + SenderAddress;

        try
        {
            msg.From = new MailAddress(SenderAddress, "Some content");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("myMail@gmail.com"));
            msg.Subject = "Some Content";
            msg.Body = message;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            smtpClient.Send(msg);
            return Content("Message was sent");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Content("Something went wrong. Try again");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Instead of sending each parameter separately, create (for instance EmailModel) and post this model to SendMail(EmailModel model) action

2) On the end of SendMail(MailModel model) action, just return the same view with the same model but with flag like: model.IsSuccess = true

3) Check this flag on the view:

```
@if(model.IsSuccess)
{
   <div>Good!</div>
}
```